# php curl reset or modify cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

PHP-CURL:
How the hell can I modify or delete cookies after calling curl_exec in existing curl object?

1) "Cookiejar" file is not saved on disk until curl_close()!

2) CURLOPT_COOKIE - can't help, just adding cookie with same name, not removing/editing older one.

3) CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER - setting "Cookie: " - can't help too!

I just need to edit or totally remove that cookies without closing - re-creating curl object =(

Answer (score 0):

I think I had similar problem. Solution was cloning curl object with curl_copy_handle() and closing one of them (either original or clone). I'm not sure if this is useful for your problem.

Comment: hm, but the one that isn't  closed still have all cookies in memory, I won't be able to use it.

Comment: A bit late... You can maybe close curl, modify your cookie file, then open another curl with the modified cookie. Basically, it reloads the page. Wouldn't that work?